# PHP Refresh Page to fill HTML Dropdown

Tags: php, refresh

I have a HTML Form that is automatically filled with a variable from a SQL table. If I visit the page the dropdown is allways empty and I have to press "F5" once. Then the Dropdown is filled.

Is it possible to put a "Press of the F5 Key" once at the end of my code?

header("Refresh:0"); and other ideas I found online didn't really work.

```html
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Art der Probe</td>
      <td align="right">Type of Test Piece *</td>
      <td><select name="inputprobetype"><option value="<?php echo "$row[probe_type]"; ?>"></option><option value="Faser">Faser</option><option value="Matrix">Matrix</option><option value="Halbzeug trocken">Halbzeug trocken</option><option value="Halbzeug ausgehaertet">Halbzeug ausgehaertet</option></select></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" /><input type="reset" value=" Abbrechen"></td>
    </tr>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *header("Refresh:0"); and other ideas I found online didn't really work.* - Oh; how so?

Comment: `<input type="button" value="Reload Page/F5" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">`

Comment: Would you prefer that the dropdown is filled on the first page load?

Comment: Could you check which is the document source before pressing F5? I really do not foresee any good reason for not seeing the select properly without any refreshing!!

Comment: I think  your code producing error.Turn on error reporting and see the error

Comment: Fred- ii-: Thanks, but I would like to have it done automatically and not by the user. Otherwise I would just tell them to press F5, but that's just the worst case if I can't find a solution today.
bloodyknuckles: Yes, would even be the better solution. Can I change something that it is done?

Comment: You'll need to post more code. I can't possibly guess how the rest of it is, and give you a concrete answer.

Comment: If you want it done automatically, you've no choice but to use a header, or a JS method, different than what I've posted earlier, but similar.